# Combine date and time then add selected hours

Tags: php, date, time

I'm trying to add some hours to a date dynamically.
 I have a date, time and hours variable.
 $appdate is in the format of 2013/03/23
 $time is in military time format 13:00:00
 $rei equals hours but it's in a plain number format from 0-48.

I'm trying to combine the $appdate and the $time together then add the $rei hours selected to it to end with $reiexpires in standard mysql format. 2013-03-23 20:00:00

```
 $reitime = date('H',strtotime($rei));
 $reidate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($appdate.$time));
 $reiexpires = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($reidate + $reitime));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$appdate = "2013/03/23";
$time = "13:00:00";
$rei = 48;

$reitime = strtotime($appdate . " " . $time . " + " . $rei . " hours");
$reiexpires = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $reitime);

echo $reiexpires;
```

Output:

```
2013-03-25 13:00:00
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for clearing that up for me. Your example makes working with dates in php a little less painful for me.LOL